# C# Memory Usage Do Not Decrease

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have an C# app (created on Visual Studio with .NET Core) that uses Google Sheets API to use google sheets as database(read/upgrade/add data). But i have a problem with memory usage. I know C# has garbage collector. So i don't need to worry about memory usage but if the data that is kept on google sheets is very big (like 20k rows and 10 columns), memory usage goes to 200 MBs and it doesn't decrease anyway. Here i want to talk about my code because i think i do not code it rightly. On my app, there are different pages and they're use control objects. When every switching page buttons are clicked, these user control objects are created. Here an example what happens one of these pages on load;

```
public partial class StokKayitlari : UserControl
{
    IList<IList<Object>> StokKayitlariListe;
    private async void StokKayitlari_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Enabled = false;
        try
        {
            StokKayitlariListe = await Form1.requests.StokKayitlariniAl();
            foreach (IList<Object> StokKaydi in StokKayitlariListe)
            {
                StokKayitlariTable.Rows.Add(StokKaydi[0], StokKaydi[2], StokKaydi[1], StokKaydi[4], StokKaydi[3], StokKaydi[5], StokKaydi[7]);
                if (Int32.Parse(StokKaydi[3].ToString()) <= Int32.Parse(StokKaydi[6].ToString()))
                {
                    KritikSayidakilerTable.Rows.Add(StokKaydi[0], StokKaydi[2], StokKaydi[1], StokKaydi[3]);
                }

            }
            KritikSayidakilerTable.ClearSelection();
            this.Enabled = true;
        }
        catch
        {
            this.Enabled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Stok kayıtları yüklenirken bir hata oluştu. Lütfen bağlantınızı kontrol edip tekrar deneyin !", "Hata !", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }
    }
```

}

`IList<IList<Object>> StokKayitlariListe` that is the object where i keep readed data. `Form1.requests.StokKayitlariniAl()` this function gets the data. Every on load this page, new StokKayitlari object is created but memory usage increases and don't decrease if i click another page. I'm not sure these list objects doesn't collect by garbage collector even i switch the page. Is my way creating pages wrong ? Is there anyway to avoid huge memory using or decrease it? I know my explanation was not clear but i'm not sure where is the problem so i want to explain everything how my app works.

Comment: Does the amount of elements inside `StokKayitlariListe` increases every time  ?

Comment: No, i create new object. I also tried equaling this lists to null before switching page but it didn't work.

Comment: This is likely a non-issue. Keep in mind that the runtime won't release memory back to the OS unless you're low on physical memory. Memory usage growing forever may signal a problem, but memory usage not going down isn't a sign that anything is wrong.

Comment: what about `KritikSayidakilerTable` ?

Comment: Actually it grows every getting data and it don't decrease whatever i do.

Comment: I do not remember *exactly*, it was long time ago, but it has something to do with Tab control  - I believe you use it, when talking about pages.

Comment: KritikSayidakilerTable is datagridview object in StokKayitlari class. When the page switch or reload, new StokKayitlari class is created, so is KritikSayidakilerTable. @Tigran

Comment: Before trying to find the memory leak I would use a profiler to force a garbage collector sweep, that way you can verify if there is an actual memory leak to begin with.

Most garbage collectors (including the CLR GC) will not immediately free memory, they'll free it when they're low on memory or something similar.

Comment: I've checked other apps like Spotify and if we get new data, usage of memory increases and doesn't decrease. I think it's not a problem.